# How to configure function state storage for Pulsar running on Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, apache-pulsar

We have recently been working on migrating our Pulsar cluster to run on Kubernetes. We have successfully moved over basic functionality as well as our sinks, however we have been struggling with our functions.
We have two functions, both use state values, however when they are called, we get the following error when they try to access their state:

```
2023-04-28T07:58:33,565+0000 [public/tracking/playStartFunction-0] ERROR function-playStartFunction - Failed to process multi-cam message
java.lang.IllegalStateException: State public/tracking/playStartFunction is not enabled.
```

Our current cluster runs on EC2 instances and we configure Pulsar using Ansible. In this set up we define the following value:

```
# the service url points to bookkeeper table service
stateStorageServiceUrl: bk://{{ bookie_url }}:4181
```

We can't, however, seem to find an equivalent for this in our new K8s deployment.

Does anyone have experience running stateful functions on a K8s Pulsar cluster that could help?

We have looked through the official HELM chart but were unable to find any properties which seemed relevant.